# gmapping [SKIP] No rule to make target None

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-groovy, gmapping, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm am trying to build gmapping from source and for some reason it's not building the executables....

In a rosbuild workspace I used:

```
rosws set slam_gmapping --git git@github.com:dawonn/slam_gmapping.git
rosws update gmapping
source ./setup.bash
roscd gmapping
rosmake
```

> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> gmapping [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< gmapping [SKIP] No rule to make target None

```
$ rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping
```

> [rosrun] Couldn't find executable
> named slam_gmapping below
> /home/dereck/rosbuild_ws/slam_gmapping/gmapping

```
rosrun gmapping < tab > < tab >
```

> libconfigfile.so       liblog.so              libsensor_base.so      libsensor_range.so     test_map.py
> libgridfastslam.so     libscanmatcher.so      libsensor_odometry.so  libutils.so

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59035/gmapping-%5Bskip%5D-no-rule-to-make-target-none/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-24**:
It's hard to tell what version of that repository to use. The **master** branch has a different commit signature than what looks like the latest release, tagged **slam_gmapping-1.2.7**. You might try that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

after running rosmake:

```
roscd gmapping
cd build
make
```

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0